# React redux counter example from a array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to create an example of a counter with React and Redux, but I can not update the status of the current item in which it was clicked.

The click event, i pass the id in the payload of the current item clicked.

```
return this.props.peliculas.map(movie => {
        return <li onClick={() => this.handleClicks(movie.id)} key=
{movie.id}>{movie.title}</li>
});
```

I have function in the class to handle the event:

```
handleClicks(peli){
    this.props.onLiClick(peli);
}
```

The dispatch part:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        peliculas: state.movies.peliculas
    }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        onLiClick: (id) => dispatch({ type: 'ADD_CLICK', payload: {id} })
    }
};
```

The reducer

```
const laspelis = {
    peliculas: [{title: 'T1', id: 1, clicks: 0}, {title: 'T2', id: 2, clicks: 0}],
    isActive: false
};


export const movies = (state= laspelis, action) => {

    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_CLICK':

        //How to update the current item inside of the reducer?
        // After click the current item add 1 to the clicks property
        // If the item has id: 2 => {title: 'T2', id: 2, clicks: 1}

        return {
           ...state,
           peliculas: [{title: 'Otro 1', id:1},{title: 'Otro 2', id:2}]
        }

        default:
            break;
    }
    return state;
};
```

I have the click event linked correctly and the action is sent to the reducer,(I'm just going to show the code partially)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find an item to update by id, replace it with a new one, and not to forget to change entire array

```
   return {
       ...state,
       peliculas: state.peliculas.map(item => {
         if(item.id === payload.id) {
            return { ...item, clicks: item.clicks + 1}
         }

         return item;
       })
    }
```

Comment: It works, thank you, I'm still getting used to my mind to think differently so as not to mutate the data.